# Safari: save webpage with CSS / images folders

Tags: safari, google-chrome, web-browser, html

I'm trying to save a webpage to my computer, and I'm not having any luck doing it with Chrome... so instead I'm trying Safari.

I would like it so that it saves all the CSS and images in their respective folders, aswell as a separate .html file.

I only seem to have the following options:

1. Save a 'webarchive' file that has all html / css / images combined into one
2. Save just a .html page with all the html / css linking to those on the live site

Is it possible for me to do this using Safari?

[image]

Comment: I could have *sworn* that the webarchive format was better than that XML nonsense with encoded everything in it. Firefox **will** do that if you ask it to save a web page. You'll get a folder with the resources in it and an HTML file that references those files that looks like the source page. But that ain't Safari, sorry...

Comment: Thanks I'll give FF a go, hopefully I have better luck with that than Chrome... main reason for me wanting it saved as a web page is because I need to modify the HTML / CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free tool [WebArchive Extractor](http://robrohan.github.io/WebArchiveExtractor/) by Rob Rohan can extract the individual files from a `.webarchive`. Hope this helps!

[image: Screenshot showing a webarchive file, the main window of the WebArchive Extractor app, and the resulting folder produced by that app.]